# How to include Bootstrap JS file in HTML when installed using "npm i bootstrap"

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to make collapsible navbar using bootstarp. I had downloaded bootstrap using npm.

How to include the Bootstrap JS file to make navbar collapsible?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solution that should work:-

1. if you added that `bootstrap js` in `script tag` with `node module path`  than import
   specific function through this line in script tag.

`<script> window('bootstrap_node_module_name') </script>`

---

2. `<script type="module" src="node_module/bootstrap_file_name"></script>`

---

3. add `cdn link` or download bootstrap script `without npm`.

Comment: i would suggest go with solution 3rd. so you will not have dependencies when you deploy the code.

Comment: I tried to import like:
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Still Collapsible navbar is not working.

Comment: I just wanted to try out using npm i bootstrap

Comment: what error is showing?? you have included this bootstrap file alreay .  what output is coming.

Answer (score 0):

In your `angular.json` add the file paths to the `styles` and `scripts` array in under `build` target as such:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng6",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css","node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
          },
```

Answer (score -1):

NPM installs packages in `node_modules` directory. You will have to import the bootstrap from there.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```